# AWS Lambda cannot handle many requests quickly even though I'm below concurrency limits

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, concurrency

#### Background

I have an AWS Lambda which is hosting a Node Express app. The app has an endpoint which I need to call many times in parallel, let's say 30 times. This endpoint does some webscraping which means it takes 1-3 minutes to complete for each request.

#### Problem

If while running these 30 requests, I query another endpoint on the same Lambda which usually runs very quickly (10 seconds), the endpoint won't start execution until most of the other requests are complete (in about 3 minutes). My concurrency limit is set to 1000 and no one else is calling the Lambda at the moment.

#### Question

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I know that AWS Lambda won't necessarily spin up a new instance with every request but is there a way to make it do so so that these long-lasting actions don't block other shorter-lasting actions?

Comment: "no one else is calling the Lambda at the moment" this is unconvincing evidence.  I would put my faith in the cloudwatch metrics that will show concurrent invocations.  It sounds like a concurrency limit.  30 concurrent lambda executions is not a lot and lambda won't have any problems handling them.  Is it possible that you're misdiagnosing something else, like data plane contention?  Or could the lambdas be leaving their instances in an unhealthy state?

Comment: Are you pulling the work to do from SQS?

Comment: Why are you "hosting" a Node Express app in AWS Lambda?

Comment: what's wrong with hosting a node express app in lambda?  for low volume apis, lambda is a heck of a lot cheaper than running a server 24/7

Comment: @erik258 When I say that no one else is calling the Lambda at the moment I mean that I've verified in the logs that I'm the only one invoking this Lambda. You're right though, I think I've been partly misdiagnosing this. I have been invoking this endpoint directly instead of through API Gateway. If I invoke it through API Gateway the concurrency issue goes away. The only problem with this is that API Gateway can only handle requests shorter than 30 second which mine fail to do :(

Comment: @stdunbar no I'm not currently doing this. Is this a valid alternative to API Gateway for requests longer than 30 seconds?

Comment: stdunbar already suggested a good approach: put the work on an SQS queue.  Respond to the client with a uinque Request Id that is also in the SQS queue.  when the request is processed, track it under the request Id so the client can request the status later on.  In other words, decouple client response from workload processing.

Comment: Note that if this is a new AWS account, your Lambda concurrent execution quota will be significantly below the documented 1000 concurrent executions per the note [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html).